# Implement a window to log in LinkedIn in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, linkedin-api

I'm working in an mvc5 application where users have their own profiles, there should be a button which would open a pop-up window so that an individual user logs into LinkedIn as to sync his/her LinkedIn profile picture with our site's.

I don't think it can be implemented with modals because there's page navigation involved, so I thought about what I stated previously: a pop-up, is there a way to do this via javascript? Like, opening a pop-up and expecting a response to determine if the user logged in. If there is a better way, any info would be greately appreciated, my aim is to be able to sync the profile picture without having the user to get redirected to linked in from their profile view, I want them to change it from there and not leave the view. Is it possible to do so?

EDIT: To clarify, getting the image URL is not a problem, what I need to do is get the url from the profile window, which comes from the popup window.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at their API it is well documented. You'll need additional permissions to retrieve the full profile. [LinkedIn Profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api)

Comment: I can already log in and retrieve info, what I want to do is get it from a popup

Comment: used popup to authenticating user if you want more information read API Document

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Javascript SDK:

```
$('#btnSyncLinkedInPicture').on('click',
    function () {
        var myID = 3;
        IN.User.authorize(function () {

            IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(picture-url)").result(function (data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/MyController/MyAction?pictureUrl= ' + data.pictureUrl + '&id=' + myID,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#imgProfilePicture').attr('src', result);
                    }
                });
            }).error(function () {

            });

        });

    });
```

First, we authorize the user which will open a pop-up window so that we authenticate, the SDK will abstract us from the OAuth process. After authenticating, we may want to write a callback function, in which we can already perform REST calls via the SDK methods (you can do it elsewhere as long as you have successfully authenticated).